# C string length is coming wrong

Tags: c, strlen

I'm expecting string length to be 4 but when I'm doing `strlen()` it's coming to 0. There's no error during compiling.
I am not able to understand the reason behind this.

Here's my code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int N = 6;
    char s[4];
    int i = 0;
    while(N!=0) {
        int rem = N%2;
        N = N/2;
        //printf("%d\n", rem);
        s[i] = rem;
        i++;
    }
    //s[0] = 1;
    printf("size = %zu", strlen(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Where do you nul-terminate `s` and *Never Skimp on Buffer Size*. `char s[64];` makes much more sense along with `while (i < 63 && N != 0) { ...` to protect your array bounds -- reserving 1-char for `'\0'`, with `s[i] = 0;` after you exit the loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, `4` is a tiny buffer, don't skimp on buffer size (even though it would work if all goes perfect). When you iterate, always protect your array bounds in the loop itself. Before you can consider `s` a string, you must provide the nul-terminating character after the last **character** in the string (e.g. `'\0'` which is equivalent to plain-old `0`)

Note the bold **character** above. You are assigning the **integer value** as a character, that won't work. Convert the integer to an ASCII digit with `+ '0'`. See [ASCII Table & Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 64

int main()
{
    int i = 0, N = 6;
    char s[MAXC];               /* always use a reasonable sized buffer */
    
    while (i < MAXC - 1 && N != 0) {        /* protect array bounds */
        int rem = N % 2;
        N = N/2;
        s[i] = rem + '0';       /* convert to ASCII digit */
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate s */
    
    printf ("size = %zu (and i = %d)\n", strlen(s), i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/mod2str
size = 3 (and i = 3)
```

Let me know if you have further questions.